# How to check if iOS application uses 'StoreKit.framework'?

Tags: ios, storekit

I write SDK for iOS and I want to validate if `StoreKit.framework` is linked to application that uses my SDK, so I run:

```
if ([SKStoreProductViewController class]) {
        SKStoreProductViewController *storeController =
                        [[ SKStoreProductViewController alloc ] init ];
        // ...
    }
```

[image]

However even if `StoreKit.framework` is not linked `[SKStoreProductViewController class` still returns `true`.

How to solve this problem?

---

**Edit 1**

as @x4h1d pointed I created new empty project and added to default Controller:

```
BOOL isStoreKitAvailable = 
   (NSClassFromString(@"SKStoreProductViewController") != nil);

// => YES (there is no linked frameworks at all, why I get YES?)
```

---

**Edit 2**

My Provisioning profile has `In-App Purchase` enabled (not a project itself)

from iOS App IDs:

[image]

However from Xcode:

[image]

Maybe this is a reason why even empty application has *build-in* StoreKit?

Comment: How about `NSClassFromString(@"SKStoreProductViewController")`?

Comment: Here's the problem, I think. Importing is different from loading. _You_ have imported StoreKit. So, short of actually trying to _use_ StoreKit and crashing, you have no way to discover whether StoreKit is also actually _loaded_.

Comment: @matt `NSClassFromString(@"SKStoreProductViewController")` returns true

Comment: @matt I need verify if application uses StoreKit - open internal AppsStore else open browser. But i still didn't find solution

Comment: As matt said, `Import` and `Link`, a framework, are two different things. Both `NSClassFromString(@"SKStoreProductViewController")` and `[SKStoreProductViewController class]` will return true when you `Link` StoreKit framework. The difference is, you have to import `StoreKit.h`, too, when you use`[SKStoreProductViewController class]`. Create a new project and check `BOOL isStoreKitAvailable = (NSClassFromString(@"SKStoreProductViewController") != nil);` . Then link the framework, don't import, and check again.

Comment: You might get some ideas to solve your problem [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#include-file-checking-macros)

Comment: @x4h1d please see my edit, it still returns `YES`

Comment: Huh, I wonder why you are trying to do such a strange detection. If you are building a library, just create a configuration flag and make the behavior configurable.

Comment: @Sulthan I want to be sure if my SDK will be able to open Internal  App Store from host application or redirect him to Browser if StoreKit is not linked

Comment: have you tried with another provisioning profile which doesn't have in-app purchase inability? Though, I don't think that might be the reason. But worth a try in your case.

Comment: Can you use a terminal and do a "xcodebuild" for case where you don't link storekit.framework and case where you link "storekit.framework"? Please send me the output after doing the same. Thanks

Comment: Please try with a profile other than what you are using which doesn't have this in-app purchase ability. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can check the storekit availibility using following code.

```
func checkStoreKitAvailibility() -> Bool {
    for bundle in Bundle.allFrameworks {
        if ((bundle.classNamed("SKStoreProductViewController")) != nil) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Edit:
For Objective-C you can use:

```
- (BOOL)checkStoreKitAvailibility {

    for (NSBundle *bundle in NSBundle.allFrameworks) {
        if ([bundle classNamed:@"SKStoreProductViewController"]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Linked Frameworks and Libraries make it `Optional` instead of `Required`. So, that if the application developers wants it to implement he will mark the framework as `Required` in the application. Now if you use the `[SKStoreProductViewController class]`. it may crash use the `NSStringFromClass(@"SKStoreProductViewController")` to determine if its safe to use it.

Comment: My question is: How can I detect if Host Application linked `StoreKit.framework`  on not

Comment: To do it, weak link the required framework in your SDK and use the NSStringFromClass(@"SKStoreProductViewController") is available. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html

Answer (score 0):

```
//SWIFT 
class func allFrameworks() -> [AnyObject]

//OBJECTIVE-C
+ (NSArray *)allFrameworks
```

From NSBundle

```
+allFrameworks
Returns an array of all of the application’s bundles that represent frameworks.
```

**Return Value**

An array of all of the application’s bundles that represent frameworks. Only frameworks with one or more Objective-C classes in them are included.

**Import Statement**

```
import Foundation
```

**Availability**

```
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
```

**How to Use**

`(NSBundle.allFrameworks()` -> Return Array of All framework use in project.

You can Check Using `for` loop apllication contain `storeKit.framework` or Not as Below.

**Swift :---**

```
func isStoreKitAvailable() -> Bool {
    for frameWorkName in Bundle.allFrameworks {
        if ((frameWorkName.classNamed("SKStoreProductViewController")) != nil) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Objective C :---**

```
- (BOOL)isStoreKitAvailable {

    for (NSBundle *frameWorkName in NSBundle.allFrameworks) {
        if ([frameWorkName classNamed:@"SKStoreProductViewController"]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Find more reference from [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/bundle#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle/allFrameworks)

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode,

when we enable the `In-App purchase` under `Capabilities`, Xcode automatically links `StoreKit.framework` and `Add the In-App purchase feature to our App ID`. Similarly if our App ID already have In-App purchase enabled the same happens.

So by doing simply,

```
BOOL isStoreKitAvailable = (NSClassFromString(@"SKStoreProductViewController") != nil);
```

I hope this might help you.